# Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'MaxPool'

Tags: keras

I am trying to build a convolution layer as follows:

```py
for window_size in filter_sizes:

    conv = Convolution2D(nb_filter=1, nb_row=window_size, nb_col=nb_col,
                         border_mode='valid',
                         activation='tanh',
                         name='conv_{:d}'.format(window_size))(in_x)

    max_pool = MaxPooling2D(name='maxpool_{:d}'.format(window_size))(conv)

    convolutions.append(max_pool)
```

But I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,9,1,1].
```

I don't quite understand why this is the case. Do I have to specify the input? I thought that this is not necessary except for the model inputs?

Comment: what are nb_row, nb_col, window_size ? Do you know that using this layer without specifying the pool_size sets it by default to (2,2)? What is probably happening is that you try to max pool a tensor of size (1,2) or (1,1) with a window (2,2)... which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @NassimBen You were right on this one. Turned out that it was just me not fully understanding what the input parameters are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem before.Every time you use Maxpooling(pool_size=[2,2]),image_size will be reduced by 2 times.Maybe the parameter has been smaller than 2, so that you cannot use Maxpool again.
Hope that would be useful to you.^_^